# Detect name of computer that a WP7 is connected to via the USB cable

Tags: windows-phone-7

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842534/send-data-from-wp7-phone-to-pc-via-usb-cable) I know it is possible to send data from a WP7 to the computer is connected via WCF service. I have a solution set up to this and it works quite well. The only problem is I must either hard code the name of the host computer or allow the user to configure it on the device themselves.

I would prefer to have this happen automatically, so is there a way to detect the name of the computer that the WP7 is connected to.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to query information about the host machine from within your app.
There would be a large potential security hole if an app could query information about the PC it was connected to.

Comment: So there's no way to write an app that connect automatically to an app running on the host computer? This does seem a bit limiting.

Comment: @Robert not currently. Have both apps talk to a web/cloud service in the mean time. They would also not need to be connected physically.